# Making a list in HTML from value of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I need a help to make a list using JavaScript.

What I’m trying to do is if user clicked submit button elements in textarea making a list in HTML.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main">
            <img src="">
        </div>
        </br>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Guest List:</h3>
            <textarea id="text"></textarea>
            </br>
            <button id="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class = "guestList">
            <div id="list"></div>
        </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function submit(){
    var guestName = document.getElementById('text');
    var listData = [guestName];
    var listContainer = document.getElementById('list');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(listContainer);
    var listElement = document.createElement("ul");
    guestName.appendChild(listElement);
    var numberOfListItems = listData.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfListItems; ++i){
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.innerHTML = listData[i];
        listElement.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well

Comment: `numberOfListItems = listData.length;` this will always be `1`. You probably want to `split()` the value of the `textarea`. Assuming the element with ID `text` is your textarea the third line needs to be `var listData = guestName.value.split(` _delimiter_ `);` where the delimiter is the seperator in the text field (is it a line break? Then use `'\n'`. A semicolon? Use a `';'`, etc.).

Comment: And please keep in mind: for future posts always include your **input** and the expected and the actual **output** in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here’s the fixed code and below are all the explanations, etc.

#### Full fixed code along with some other improvements

```js
function submit(){
    var guestName=document.getElementById('text');
    var listData=guestName.value.split('\n');

    var listContainer=document.getElementById('list'),
        listElement=document.createElement("ul");
    listContainer.appendChild(listElement);

    var numberOfListItems=listData.length;
    var listItem;
    for(var i=0; i<numberOfListItems; ++i){
        listItem=document.createElement("li");
        listItem.innerHTML=listData[i];
        listElement.appendChild(listItem);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="main">
            <img src="" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Guest List:</h3>
            <textarea id="text"></textarea>
            <br/>
            <button id="submit" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="guestList">
            <div id="list"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### Explanations

```
numberOfListItems = listData.length;
```

This will always be 1. The line defining `listData` is problematic:

```
var listData = [guestName];
```

`listData` is now just an array containing only the *textarea element*.

The proper way of getting the individual names out of the textarea is to `split()` the value of the textarea. I’m going to assume that the guest list in your textarea is separated by line breaks as I write the proper code:

```
var guestName = document.getElementById('text');
  // assigns the element to guestName
var listData = guestName.value.split('\n');
  // listData is now an Array that contains every line in the textarea
```

This makes use of [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which takes a delimiter as an argument and turns a string into an array based on the separators.

---

This following line re-appends an element already present in the DOM… to the DOM… which is kind of unnecessary:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(listContainer);
```

---

This line is problematic as well:

```
guestName.appendChild(listElement);
```

`<textarea>`s can’t have child elements. You most likely wanted to append that child to `listContainer`.

---

The loop adds an `<li>` element to the `<ul>` per “guest”. It should work fine *now* with all the other flaws fixed.

---

A few remakrs to your HTML:

1. `<img src="">` should at least be `<img src="" alt=""/>` — a missing `alt` attribute is invalid
2. Each `</br>` should be a `<br/>`
3. The `</div>` for `<div class="container">` is missing